# Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My app keeps on crashing on launch because of several errors.

1. java.lang.InvocationTargetException
2. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Here is the logcat error for the second exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1137)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:1013)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1092)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1062)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:599)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3961)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1064)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:968)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:103)
    at com.example.moveapplication.utils.MAFTextViewBold.<init>(MAFTextViewBold.kt:8)
        ... 72 more
```

From the last line it says my error is from my MAFTextViewBold.kt file

```
class MAFTextViewBold (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs){
init {
    applyFont()
}

private fun applyFont() {
    val typeface:Typeface =
        Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "Montserrat-Bold.ttf")
    setTypeface(typeface)
}
```

}

What could be causing the error? It was compiling before but after I did a factory reset on Android Studio I could not ran my app. The erros started showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the exceptions were brought by using a complex color that could not be translated.
see the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
```

This color `android:textColor="@color/aquamarine"` can not be converted properly as applied in my **MAFTextView** class. Even on a normal TextView it still can't be converted.
I changed the color to black and my app was running again.
Android Development always finds a way to amaze me. Just a color change throws two exceptions.smh

Answer (score 0):

Since it's work before, check your build grade, make sure it's Java_8 and try upgrade your kotlin version to the latest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).